# Is Maintaining a pointer still Stateless?

Tags: api, pointers, message-queue, worker, stateless

I'm trying to design an API that maintains an array of message queues and takes requests from workers to process items in the MQs in a round-robin fashion to ensure fairness. In order to move through the array as worker requests come in, the API would need to maintain a pointer for which MQ to pop and serve up next. Does maintaining a pointer make this no longer stateless? Or is it still stateless because the pointer is not related to any sort of client context?

Comment: Your business logic might be stateless, but your infra-layer doing the round-robin scheduling is definitely not stateless (clearly, it needs to remember who was last to know who will be next)

Comment: Think of stateless-ness in terms of its definition, but in terms of it consequences. A stateless service is one that I kill, and eventually spin back up. It would resume with no observable change in behaviour. It would be able to use a read-only image/container/whatever, and not need any instance storage. Integration tests against it don't require any "setup" code (akin to testing a pure function).

Comment: Thanks for the input @Alexander, I guess the line is a little blurry to me in this case because in the event of a failure, the change in behavior is so minor that it doesn't really matter. (Starting over from the first element, eventually it will get back to where it was and its still processing in the mean time), but I guess a minor change in bahaviour is still a change nonetheless. Can you think of a way to achieve this round-robin approach while remaining stateless? Is it possible do you think?

Comment: Well fundamentally all computers are stateful (thing of registers, RAM, ...). It's a matter of where you "draw the line". "the change in behavior is so minor that it doesn't really matter." then it's probably de-facto stateless and you can treat it as such.

Comment: I see, makes sense, if its practical then thats all that really matters. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: I just realized I my reasoning was roughly circular. I was saying "if you can treat it as stateless, then it's de-facto stateless", yet also "if it's stateless, you can treat it as such". Both statements are only true if you distinguish "de-facto stateless" (as a conclusion based on how you know you can treat it), and "stateless" (truely stateless, from in a proven manner)